# How datetime.datetime.now() works without internet connection?

Tags: python, datetime, time, clock, real-time-clock

In python, by importing **datetime module** and using various functions of `class datetime.datetime` we could get basic dates with formatting and even date arithmetic for deployment.

For example, **datetime.datetime.now()** will return today's date.

[image]

But, today when I run this program there was no internet connection in my computer but still it outputs today's date.

So, how `datetime.datetime.now()` could return proper date? Is the algorithm automatically increments after 24 hours time ?

Comment: Why would the code ask some other machine for the date and time when your computer knows it?

Comment: Well, the computer knows how without internet connection ?

Comment: Because it has a clock inside it?

Comment: @W.Jack Think about your BIOS - it maintains the time without leveraging the web. All computers have a battery that helps keep RTC functioning, as well as minor memory benefits.

Comment: @W.Jack it utilized the system time. Your system clock. Try change your computer clock and run it again to see the changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr `datetime.datetime.now()` uses the clock built into your computer.**

Computers have been able to keep fairly accurate time for much longer than the Internet has existed.

For example, PCs feature what's called a [real-time clock](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/mswish/ut-rtc.html) (RTC). It is battery-powered and can keep the time even when the computer is switched off.

Interestingly, some distributed algorithms [require very accurate clocks](http://www.wired.co.uk/article/google-gps-powered-database) in order to operate reliably. The required accuracy far exceeds anything that a simple oscillator-based clock can provide.

As a result, companies like Google operate [GPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_disciplined_oscillator) and [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_clock) clocks in their data centres (and even those are not without potential issues, as was demonstrated, for example, [on 26 January 2017](http://www.insidegnss.com/node/4831#), when some GPS clocks were out by 13 microseconds for ten hours).

Even though the data centres are connected to the Internet, neither GPS nor atomic clocks require an Internet connection to operate. Besides, [*someone*](http://www.pool.ntp.org/en/) needs to keep all that Internet time infrastructure running... it can't be that everyone gets their time "off the Internet". ;)

Now that we're on the subject of distributing the time across computer networks, the main protocols for doing that are [NTP (Network Time Protocol) and PTP (Precision Time Protocol)](https://www.masterclock.com/support/library/network-timing-ntp-vs-ptp/).

Comment: Worth mentioning is also NTP service which can synchronize the local clock with a remote time server.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Never really thought about this yet been alive for decades.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `datetime.datetime.now()` does not state the time is received from the internet.

> Return the current local date and time. If optional argument tz is
>   None or not specified, this is like today(), but, if possible,
>   supplies more precision than can be gotten from going through a
>   time.time() timestamp (for example, this may be possible on platforms
>   supplying the C gettimeofday() function).
>
> If tz is not None, it must be an instance of a tzinfo subclass, and
>   the current date and time are converted to tz’s time zone. In this
>   case the result is equivalent to
>   tz.fromutc(datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=tz)). See also today(),
>   utcnow().

The `datetime` is received from the computer time, if you are running windows for example, try to change time from the window and the python will print the time that you changed.

check its documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: That's not what "local time" means. It means "in the computer's timezone", not "without consulting external sources". http://www.dictionary.com/browse/local-time